# Why does the grub menu list two different versions of Ubuntu to boot into after I upgraded?

Tags: grub2

I successfully upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10, albeit with a bit of a struggle. 
However, after upgrading to 10.10, I rebooted to find that I had a new option. Windows XP, Ubuntu 10.10 AND Ubuntu 10.04.

I was wondering why the new upgrade didn't overwrite the original 10.04 install. I have yet to boot from the 10.04 again. Is this common?

Comment: Please boot Ubuntu and update your question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: open a terminal, type `sudo update-grub`, hit enter and type your password (there won't be any stars or so) and hit enter again. Wait a little, and reboot your computer. Did this erase the Ubuntu 10.04 entry?

If it doesn't, try to select the 10.04 entry and boot on it. Please edit your question to explain what happens.